# Добавление дублей из таблицы (вложенный цикл for) DataTable

Tags: c#, desktop

Нужно чтобы этот алгоритм добавил те строки, которых нет в `DataTable globalDataMySQL` из таблицы `DataTable globalDataExcel`. В данный момент добавляет строки и которые есть и которых нет. Пример приложил на скриншотах.

Код:

```
                for (int i = 0; i < globalDataTableMySQL.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    if (globalDataTableMySQL.Rows[i].RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                    {
                        
                        for (int j = 0; j < globalDataTableExcel.Rows.Count; ++j)
                        {
                            bool found = false;
                            if (globalDataTableMySQL.Rows[j][0].ToString() == globalDataTableExcel.Rows[i][0].ToString())
                            {
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            if (!found)
                            {
                                globalDataTableMySQL.Rows.Add(globalDataTableExcel.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                                ++plusSlov;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Таблица `globalDataTableExcel`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица `globalDataTableMySQL`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат нажатия кнопки (приведение в действие алгоритма)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наиболее полезный из ответов стоит отметить принятым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение. Пока работает корректно, не знаю как, но работает

```
                for (int i = 0; i < globalDataTableExcel.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    if (globalDataTableExcel.Rows[i].RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                    {
                        bool found = false;
                        for (int j = 0; j < globalDataTableMySQL.Rows.Count; ++j)
                        {
                            if (globalDataTableExcel.Rows[i][0].ToString() == globalDataTableMySQL.Rows[j][0].ToString())
                            {
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!found)
                        {
                            globalDataTableMySQL.Rows.Add(globalDataTableExcel.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                            ++plusSlov;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Хотите более короткий код?

Comment: @Neomaster если есть вариант по-лучше и удобнее, я не против

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде есть ряд ошибок ошибок. Указывать на каждую ошибку - достаточно долго. Если кратко - основные моменты:

1. `if (!found)` конструкция должна быть за пределами внутреннего
   цикла.
2. Внешний цикл должен быть по `Excel` - строкам.
3. В своей версии вы запутались в индексах `i` и `j`. Например, в
   строке кода:

   ```
   if (globalDataTableExcel.Rows[i][0].ToString() == globalDataTableMySQL.Rows[j][0].ToString())
   ```

   У вас ошибка. Индекс `i` - это индекс по `MySql` строкам, а `j` - по
   `Excel`

Я предпочел уйти от индексов и использовать `foreach`. Моя версия итогового варианта:

```
foreach (DataRow excelRow in globalDataTableExcel.Rows)
{
    bool found = false;

    foreach (DataRow sqlRow in globalDataTableMySQL.Rows)
    {
        if (sqlRow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted && // Не знаю, для чего вы добавили условие на Deleted, я его оставил
            sqlRow[0].ToString() == excelRow[0].ToString())
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        var newSqlRow = globalDataTableMySQL.NewRow();
        newSqlRow[0] = excelRow[0];
        globalDataTableMySQL.Rows.Add(newSqlRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: чтобы не путаться в индексах колонок и строк лучше использовать ассоциативный индекс Row["ColumnName"]. Каждый раз придется вспоминать/проверять у какой колонки какой индекс, в БД порядок столбцов может быть изменен.

Comment: @Neomaster да, но тут тоже есть подводные камни. Например, если столбец переименуется

Answer (score 2):

**Решение на LINQ**

```
globalDataTableExcel.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Where(x => globalDataTableMySQL.Rows
        .Cast<DataRow>()
        .Any(y => (int)y["num"] != (int)x["num"]))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => globalDataTableMySQL.Rows.Add(x["num"]));
```

Если у вас будет строка из 20 колонок, вы заколебетесь с индексами... Используйте ассоциативный индекс `Row[ColumnName]`, не нужно будет каждый раз вспоминать/перепроверять у какой колонки какой номер, тем более порядок столбцов в БД может быть изменен.

Вы используйте устаревший подход работы с БД. В .NET есть **LINQ** и **Entity Framework**, которые намного упрощают жизнь, обязательно посмотрите их.

Данные, с которыми работал

```
#region Подготовка данных
string[] names =
{
    "Тестировщиков Тест Тестович",
    "Безопасников Безопас Безопасникович",
    "Заказчиков Заказ Заказович",
};

// globalDataTableMySQL.
DataTable globalDataTableExcel = new DataTable();
globalDataTableExcel.Columns.Add("num", typeof(int));
globalDataTableExcel.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    DataRow row = globalDataTableExcel.NewRow();
    row["num"] = i;
    row["name"] = names[i];
    globalDataTableExcel.Rows.Add(row);
}

// globalDataTableMySQL.
DataTable globalDataTableMySQL = new DataTable();
globalDataTableMySQL.Columns.Add("num", typeof(int));
DataRow sqlRow = globalDataTableMySQL.NewRow();
sqlRow["num"] = 1;
globalDataTableMySQL.Rows.Add(sqlRow);
#endregion
```

Comment: Мне кажется, у столбца `num` строковый тип данных. Число `375291401414` не влезет в `int`

Comment: Наверно. В вопросе не указано. В любом случае надо приводить к `(string)` в `Any()`, чтобы сравнение шло как значимых типов.